# Compiler: How is class instantiation code compiled?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, runtime, interpreter, jit

Assume we have (in C++): `MyClass* x = new MyClass(10)`

Can someone please explain what 'exactly' happens when compiler parses this statement? (I tried taking a look at the Red Dragon book but couldn't find anything useful).

I want to know what happens in the stack/heap or compiler's symbol table. How compiler keeps track of the type of `x` variable? How later calls to `x->method1(1,2)` will be resolved to appropriate methods in MyClass (for simplicity assume there is no inheritance and `MyClass` is the only class that we have).

Comment: Note that the Dragon Book, while it's an in-depth look at compilers, doesn't consider languages which are as complex as modern C++. In particular, due to templates compiling C++ code is Turing-complete.

Comment: However, the Dragon Book does have a decent explanation of compiler phases. Your doubts about " what happens in the stack/heap or compiler's symbol table" suggest that you are not aware of those phases. Stack/heap  is considered quite late in the process, in code generation, whereas the symbol table exists in almost the first stage (C++ has a preprocessor with its own symbol table, but that's not relevant for the declaration shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass* x` is a definition of pointer to object (instance) of type `MyClass`. Memory for that variable is allocated according to the place of its definition: if it is defined in the method, and is a local variable, stack is used. And it is memory to store the address.

Then expression `new MyClass(10)` is a command to allocate memory in heap for an object (instance) itself and return address to be stored in `x`. To fill the memory of new object `MyClass` (set up its initial state) special method (at least one) is executed automatically - constructor (or several in some cases) - that receives value `10` in your example.

Because C++ allows inheritance (this is also the reason for the execution of several constructors when an instance created) there are some mechanism to determine which method should be exactly called. You should read somewhere about [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

In the simplest case (without inheritance), type of variable `x` (pointer to object of type `MyClass`) provide all necessary information about object structure. So, `x->method1(1,2)` or `(*x).method1(1,2)` provide call of member `method1` to execute it with parameters `1` and `2` (stored in stack) as well as with data that form the state of object (stored in heap) and available by `this` pointer inside any non-static member of class. The method itself, of course, not stored in the heap.

**UPDATE:**

You can make example to make same experiments, like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    int innerData;
    long long int lastValue;
public:
    MyClass() // default constructor
    {
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
        innerData = 42;
        lastValue = 0;
    }
    MyClass(int data) // constructor with parameter
    {
        cout << "constructor with parameter" << endl;
        innerData = data;
        lastValue = 0;
    }
    int method1(int factor, int coefficient)
    {
        cout << "Address in this-pinter " << this << endl;
        cout << "Address of innerData " << &innerData << endl;
        cout << "Address of lastValue " << &lastValue << endl;
        cout << "Address of factor " << &factor << endl;
        lastValue = factor * innerData + coefficient;
        return lastValue;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass* x = new MyClass(10);
    cout << "addres of object " << x << endl;
    cout << "addres of pointer " << &x << endl;
    cout << "size of object " << sizeof(MyClass) << endl;
    cout << "size of pointer " << sizeof(x) << endl;
    x->method1(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is indeed a bit nasty, and this already started in C. Just look at the first 3 tokens : `MyClass * x`. The compiler has to look up `MyClass` to determine that this is *not* a multiplication. Since it is a type, it shouldn't look up `x` either, but add `x` to the symbol table right there (really can't be delayed). In the ideal world of simple-to-parse languages, there would be no need to keep the symbol table up to date for every token parsed.

After the definition of `x`, the `=` signals an initializing expression. That's an easy one to parse: `new` is unambiguously a keyword, it's not a placement `new` and the type being created is right there.